# How can I install an application on iPhone automatically?

Tags: c++, iphone

I need a way to install a distribuible application without user intervention, of course I currently have a distribution profile installed on my device (I can install or uninstall the application by means of iTunes or iPCU), the problem remain on the side of automation "no user intervention is required", basically I need to develop a software (maybe hack iTunesMobileDevice.dll) that install the application when a valid device (the one with a valid distribution profile) is connected to one machine (application server), so any ideas??....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

There is absolutely nothing in the standard API that will let you do this. I can't image a bigger security hole than a mechanism for installing software without the users intervention/knowledge. If Apple did find such a hole they would plug it so fast it would cause physicist to question certain assumptions about the speed of light.

You might could do this on a jailbroke device but AFIK all the open development tools require human interaction. You would probably have to write quite a bit from scratch and you would have all the security and software availability problems of a jailbroken device. You would also run the risk of Apple breaking the loophole you exploited in a future release.

If I may ask, why exactly are you trying to automatically install software? What advantage do you hope to gain by undermining your security to that extent? There might be a better way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually we need to distribute our application on around 1000 devices, and we need to update the application often according new requirements, not all users have the skills (knowledge) for install the new updates, and some times updates are important for security or bussiness rules.

I know that Jailbroken device allow this function, but this is no way for us. Actually we have a legal way to distribute the application, I mean a Enterprise licence for In-House distribution. 

In simple words: "the user connects the device on host and gets updated".

Comment: There is no easy way to do this and I wouldn't be at all surprised to learn that attempting to alter the Apple supplied software e.g. iTunes or Xcode, to accomplish this would be a violation of your licensing agreement. I would have your legal people look this over before going any further. Security is a big, big part of the iPhoneOS and Apple takes the integrity of the security systems very seriously. I believe the human intervention in installing software is very intentional on Apple's part and won't be something they allow to be altered.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to research a means of using the update feature on the app store in an enterprise context. However, that will still require user intervention.