# how to install the application in iphone automatically

Tags: iphone, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install an application on iPhone automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762986/how-can-i-install-an-application-on-iphone-automatically)

I want to install my app automatically on iphone without manual intervention.Is there any scripts that can perform the installation automatically

Comment: Can you describe your scenario and desired outcome in more detail? Is jailbreaking an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Check: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html